# Getting GLOB values instead of file content

Tags: perl, hash, compare, glob

I am trying to write a script that takes in one file and compares it to the second and then outputs the difference. I had it working, but decided I wanted to get rid of any line that starts with '#."  I had to use push as .= was not working.  Ever since then I get output like

> keys = GLOB(0x23d2d48)

I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use lib '/var/www/oooOOoO/lib/Perl';

my @a1;
my @a2;
my %diff1;
my %diff2;
my @diff1;
my @diff2;

my $input_file = "/etc/mysql/conf.d/replication-slave.cnf";
my $input_file2 = "tA.cnf";

open( my $input_fh, "<", $input_file ) || die "Can't open $input_file: $!";
open( my $input_fh2, "<", $input_file2 ) || die "Can't open $input_file: $!";

@a1 = ' ';
for ($input_fh) {
    next if /^#/;
    push@a1, $_;
    }

@a2= ' ';
for ($input_fh2) {
    next if /^#/;
    push @a2, $_;
    }

@diff1{ @a1 } = @a1;
delete @diff1{ @a2 };
# %diff1 contains elements from '@a1' that are not in '@a2'


@k = (keys %diff1);
print "keys = @k\n";
```

I've tried changing keys to values, but that didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, but you're code's a little messy. I'm also not sure what you're trying to do when you assign `@diff1{@a1} = @a1`.

Try this re-write and let me know:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '/var/www/ooooOOooOoo/lib/Perl';

my $input_file = "/etc/mysql/conf.d/replication-slave.cnf";
my $input_file2 = "tA.cnf";

open my $input_fh, "<", $input_file or die "Can't open $input_file: $!";
open my $input_fh2, "<", $input_file2 or die "Can't open $input_file: $!";

my (@a1, @a2);

while(<$input_fh>){
    chomp;
    next if /^#/;
    push @a1, $_;
    }

while(<$input_fh2>){
    chomp;
    next if /^#/;
    push @a2, $_;
    }

my %diff1;

@diff1{@a1} = @a1; # What are you actually trying to do here? 
delete @diff1{@a2};

# %diff1 contains elements from '@a1' that are not in '@a2'


my @k = (keys %diff1);
print "keys = @k\n";
```

But you might want to try this approach instead:

```
my @nums1 = qw(1 2 3 4 5);

my @nums2 = qw(one two three four 5);

my (%compare1, %compare2);

foreach(@nums1){
    chomp;
    $compare1{$_} = 1;
}

foreach(@nums2){
    chomp;
    $compare2{$_} = 1;
}

foreach my $key (keys %compare1){
    print "$key\n" unless $compare2{$key};
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in this bit of code:

```
for ($input_fh) {
    next if /^#/;
    push @a1, $_;
}
```

This is creating a single element list containing a filehandle, then pushing that filehandle to `@a1`. To read from the filehandle you need to wrap it with `<>`:

```
while (<$input_fh>) {
    next if /^#/;
    push @a1, $_;
}
```

Note I've switched the `for` to a `while` as `for` imposes list context and reads the file all at once whereas `while` will read one line at a time. You can also remove:

```
@a1 = ' ';
@a2 = ' ';
```

Which just adds an extra element to both arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have loaded the two arrays, it's better to use a Perl CPAN module to do this kind of taks. I think [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Utils) is a good candidate to achieve your goals. From the module documentation:

```
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

my @a = qw( a b c d );
my @b = qw( c d e f );

# symmetric difference
my @diff = array_diff(@a, @b);

# intersection
my @isect = intersect(@a, @b);

# unique union
my @unique = unique(@a, @b);

# check if arrays contain same members
if ( !array_diff(@a, @b) ) {
        # do something
}

# get items from array @a that are not in array @b
my @minus = array_minus( @a, @b );
```

Comment: I cannot use CPAN stuff, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: just copy the sub you need in your script: https://metacpan.org/source/ZMIJ/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm